# SUMIFS for vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, sum

Good day,

How can I do like sumifs in sql query in vb.net

```
    Private Sub txtProcYM_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtProcYM.TextChanged
    Try
        query = "SELECT SUM(prdInput) FROM ProdOutput WHERE HELPER ='" & txtLot.Text & "-" & txtPartNumber.Text & "-" & txtProcess1.Text & "';"
        retrieveSingleResult(query)

        proc1QTYIn.Text = dt.Rows(0)("prdInput").ToString()


    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try


End Sub
```

here is my code. The plan is to take the Sum of column prdInput based on the helper which is txtlot txtPartnumber and txprocess.

I managed to get display the first prdinput the query found but I need the the sum of its since I have multiple txtlot partnumber and process.

Thanks

Edit: I already did the SUM(prdInput) on my query but nothing shows on the textbox.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to filter some data and then sum a column in that filtered result? If so then you already have a `WHERE` clause so you're already filtering the data. If you want to sum the data then obviously you need a to include a sum operation. You're not doing that. maybe you should do that and then come back if and when it doesn't work. I'm sure that you can find out how to sum data in SQL without much effort. If that's not what you're trying to achieve then I think that you need to clarify, because I don't know what you do want.

Comment: query = "SELECT SUM(prdInput) FROM ProdOutput WHERE HELPER  (I already input this query but nothing shows.)

Comment: You seem to be assuming that the sum of a column is named after that column. It is not. You're trying to get a value from the `prdInput` column of your `DataTable` but there is no such column. If you expect the column generated by an aggregate function to have a name then you have to provide that name. As it stands, the one and only column in your result set has no name. That means that you either have to access it by index or else give it a name yourself.

Comment: That said, why are you using a `DataTable` at all? If you want to retrieve a single value then you should just get getting the result of a call to `ExecuteScalar`. In that case, column names are irrelevant.

Comment: By the way, if you had bothered to debug your code, which would have included a proper examination of your `DataTable`, then you would have seen that there was no column with that name. You don't diagnose issue with code simply by reading the code and looking at the result. That's simply the first step. You use the debugging tools built into VS. If you don't know how to debug, you should stop what you're doing and learn. It is a vital skill for all developers.

Comment: I cant find error on debug. When I run the program it runs, its just not showing the sum on the textbox. The data are from ms access

Comment: I have no background in programming, its just some  source code I found on the internet and customizing it. So far I made 3 program that are being used until now for data monitoring. I know that I should learn the basics, and I will i just don't have enough time for now.

Thank you for your time. And sorry.

Comment: It's not the job of this site to teach you how to program. This site is for specific programming issues. You're not knowing how to program is not a specific programming issue. I have told you what the issue is and what you have to do to fix it. If you don't understand how to perform basic tasks in code then that's a reason to learn. How much time you have or don't have is not our concern.

Comment: Noted master. Thank you

Comment: You have to set an Alias for your field like (`AS Something`) -> `SELECT SUM(prdInput)  AS SumPrdInput FROM ProdOutput WHERE HELPER…….` Then detect it by `dt.Rows(0)("SumPrdInput").ToString()` as a correct way to retrieve data. or `dt.Rows(0)(0).ToString()` will be an ('bad') alternative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. You just needed to alias the column that you performed the sum aggregate on:

```
    Private Sub txtProcYM_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtProcYM.TextChanged
    Try
        query = "SELECT SUM(prdInput) AS prdInput FROM ProdOutput WHERE HELPER ='" & txtLot.Text & "-" & txtPartNumber.Text & "-" & txtProcess1.Text & "';"
        retrieveSingleResult(query)

        proc1QTYIn.Text = dt.Rows(0)("prdInput").ToString()


    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try


End Sub
```

It might be easier to see the difference with a formatted query:

```
SELECT
  SUM(prdInput) AS prdInput --you forgot to give this column a name
FROM ProdOutput
WHERE HELPER = '" & txtLot.Text & "-" & txtPartNumber.Text & "-" & txtProcess1.Text & "';
```